# How can i position a canvas and text child above gameobject?

Tags: unity, c#

Better do it automatic by script.

The Display Information in the Hierarchy is the Canvas.
Not sure if to change the Canvas Render Mode now it's on World Space.
I want the Text to be displayed above one of the Spheres for example the first Sphere.

But to do it in script to move automatic the canvas to be above the sphere or any other gameobject.

[image: Canvas]

The Text

[image: Text]

I have 5 Spheres so i want to put above each one a number text: 1,2,3,4,5
Above the first Sphere the number 1 on the second Sphere in the Hierarchy the number 2 and so on.

This is what i tried but it's not changing the canvas position at all:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class canvasui : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Canvas canvas;
    public GameObject[] waypoints;
    public Vector3[] sizes;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        waypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("waypoint");
        sizes = new Vector3[waypoints.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Length; i++)
        {
            sizes[i] = waypoints[i].GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.size;
        }

        canvas.transform.position = new Vector3(
            waypoints[0].transform.position.x,
            waypoints[0].transform.position.y + sizes[0].y / 2,
            waypoints[0].transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

I attached the script to new empty gameobject.

UPDATE:

I'm using this script now:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class canvasui : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject floatingCanvas;   /// Canvas that you wan to be above your GameObject
    public float yPadding;              /// Padding on the Y-Axis.
    private MeshRenderer renderer;      /// MeshRenderer Component.

    void Awake()
    {
        renderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 newCanvasPosition = new Vector3
                                    (
                                        transform.position.x,
                                        ((transform.position.y + renderer.bounds.extents.y) + yPadding),
                                        transform.position.z
                                    );
        floatingCanvas.transform.position = newCanvasPosition;
    }
}
```

But the text for example "1" is not above the sphere:
It's no the left bottom.

[image: text]

Comment: Have you tried taking their bounding box, use that to determine the size and then simply place your canvas element by taking the sphere position + half height of the bounding box?

Comment: @Sidar I updated my question with what i tried attached new script to new empty gameobject but it's not changing the canvas position at all.

Comment: Your update doesnt work because your canvas is in Screenspace. Set it to worldspace. https://i.imgur.com/FDdfVP7.png

Comment: @Sidar I changed it now but in game view i don't see the number 1 above the sphere and when i click on the Text in the Hierarchy while the game is running i see in the Scene view something above the Sphere not the Text 1 but something else like a propeller/vane https://imgur.com/a/lcwPj

Comment: @Sidar This is a screenshot of the canvas after changed to worldspace. https://imgur.com/a/AUcWH

Comment: I found that using Text Mesh is the easiest using LinkWindcrafter to get the position and it's working great. Instead Canvas i re position the Text Mesh.

Comment: I think you have to set the camera as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sidar suggested, you could play with the bounding box dimensions of your GameObject, and an offset to have a padding. The **Bounds** are structs, used in **Coliders**, **Mesh** and **Renderers**, you can check more about the struct in the [**Bound's API.**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html)

This is a quick example to apply it in code (here I am using MeshRenderer, but again, you can access **Bounds** from the classes previously mentioned):

```
public GameObject floatingCanvas;   /// Canvas that you wan to be above your GameObject
public float yPadding;              /// Padding on the Y-Axis.
private MeshRenderer renderer;      /// MeshRenderer Component.

void Awake()
{
    renderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
}

void Update()
{
    Vector3 newCanvasPosition = new Vector3
                                (
                                    transform.position.x,
                                    ((transform.position.y + renderer.bounds.extens.y) + yPadding),
                                    transform.position.z
                                );
    floatingCanvas.transform.position = newCanvasPosition;
}
```

Hope it helps with the positioning.

Comment: Updated my question again with your script and screenshot of what i'm getting. The Text "1" is not above the sphere it's on the left bottom corner. I tried to change the Canvas render mode to all 3 modes but it didn't put it above the sphere.

Answer (score 1):

I normally like to just create the Text and then drag the UI text and parent it to the Object.

Next pick center center for the paragraph alignment and then addcomponent  Canvas to the text itself.

Change the canvas to screenspace camera and drag the camera in the slot. now switch it back to worldspace and position the text anywhere you want.(switching it like so helps the text just not up and disappear in the game view sometimes)

From there the only scripting you would need is to just set it active when you want to see it or have it always face the camera if needed.

note: if you go this route you may have to adjust the rect scaling also to get a nice crisp view of the text. Or if it is not quite center with the object right click and reset the rect then re-scale to around 0.02-0.03 and it should work good with best fit checked.